# How to make bash autocompletion work with cabal?

Tags: bash, haskell, autocomplete, cabal, cabal-install

With `stack` build tool I need to add the following line to my system config and autocompletion works:

```
eval "$(stack --bash-completion-script stack)"
```

But autocompletion for `cabal-install` doesn't work out of the box and I can't find a way to do this. How can I enable bash autocompletion for `cabal-install` (my `cabal-install` version: `2.1.0.0`)?

My OS: Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a `cabal-install` autocomplete script here. You just need to source it somewhere in your shell: https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/master/cabal-install/bash-completion/cabal

For ubuntu, you should be able to do it by just tossing it in `/etc/bash_completion.d`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this script! Could you please provide exact command? I'm not a `bash` expert... Won't something like this work: `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/haskell/cabal/master/cabal-install/bash-completion/cabal | source`?

Comment: I mean just download the file and put it into the directory I suggested...